# My microphone has been going lower in volume and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: audio, microphone

My microphone was normal two months ago, But since that two months my microphone has seemed to  lower in volume to the point where it sounded nice at 50% and now sounds quiet at 100% and doesn't even pick up in certain games because of the volume, I am looking for some help to get it back to where it was so I can talk to my friends with out a issue, I am running a laptop with windows 11 on it with an external microphone not connected to a head set, Just need some help.

Comment: couldn't it be a hardware problem? Have you testes it in another machine?

Comment: I haven't but I really think I should get a new computer.

Comment: Open the audio control panel and check the volume setting on the mic.